# Ajax, JSON and Unicode *almost* working right for me -- where did I go wrong?

Tags: ajax, json, unicode, utf-8

I'm having trouble completing a round-trip for Ajax submission where Unicode characters are involved.  Some work, some don't.  For example, let's say that the following text is to be sent:

ǮaƉb

That text is U+01EE U+0061 U+0189 U+0062.

My Ajax call is simple:

```
ServerRequest.ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : ServerRequest.serverUrl,
    data : sendJSON,
    dataType : 'json',

    timeout: 200000,
    async : async,
    cache : false,
    error: function( [snip]
```

where sendJSON is first run through JSON.stringify().

In testing (Chrome browser) prior to calling the server, when I ask for a that note field in the debugger I see them as formatted in the browser.  They aren't displayed in any other format, such as ISO8859-1 or UTF-8.

The server sees the text in the JSON string as UTF-8.  When reconstructed into a Java object it keeps its UTF-8 value.

I now turn around and send the same data back to the browser.  On the server I dump the field containing the data:

```
        for(int ix = 0; ix < notes.length(); ix++) {
            log.info("codepoint notes[" + ix + "]: " + ((int) (notes.codePointAt(ix))) + "\n");
        }
```

I get this data:

```
codepoint op_notes[0]: 199    (which is 0xC7)
codepoint op_notes[1]: 174    (which is 0xAE)
codepoint op_notes[2]: 97     (which is 0x61)
codepoint op_notes[3]: 198    (which is 0xC6)
codepoint op_notes[4]: 137    (which is 0x89)
codepoint op_notes[5]: 98     (which is 0x62)
```

This is a UTF-8 representation of what was sent to the server.

This data is packed into a JSON object and sent to the server through HttpResponse.getWriter().write().  Our JSON libraries come from json.org.

Once the server gets this the note field has become

```
note.charCodeAt(0) = 494     (0x01EE)
note.charCodeAt(1) =  97     (0x61)
note.charCodeAt(2) = 65533   (0xFFFD, the "I don't know" value)
note.charCodeAt(3) = 137     (0x89)
note.charCodeAt(4) =  98     (0x62)
```

The first character comes back a Unicode, eating two bytes.  The 'a' eats the third byte.  But the other two-byte character doesn't get communicated correctly.  Rather, the first byte is misinterpreted or lost, replaced with the default U+FFFD.

I don't understand why the first high bit character is accepted OK but not the other one.  This slash-D isn't accepted no matter if it is sent alone or with friends.

Does someone understand this and can point at "here is your simple error" in this process?

Thanks,
Jerome.

**UPDATE**: If I add this to my server:

```
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

I get in my browser the same six UTF-8 characters the server sent it.  My problem is transformed into getting the characters to show correctly in the text field.  They display as Ç®aÆb, which is the "extended ASCII" for what I want to show.  I suppose I could run the text through a decoder, but did I miss another configuration?

Answer (score 1):

For others' reference, I solved this recently.  Mostly, I need to explicitly set the contentType to UTF-8.  The docs say that when this is absent the UTF-8 is assumed.  This is only true at this time for the Firefox browser.

Once you expressly set things the UTF-8 transfer is done and the characters end up in your server as **UTF-16**.